# Possible to Use Spring Caching with Scala

Tags: java, spring, scala, caching, spring-cache

Hi I was wondering if it's possible to leverage Spring annotated Caching within Scala.  I have tried but am receiving the error below.  I am running the application from a java package that depends on the scala package.

```
 No cache could be resolved for 'CacheableOperation[public scala.collection.immutable.List MerchantDataGateway.getAllMerchants()]
```

My Configuration Class

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx")
public class EnvironmentHelperConfig {

    @Bean
    public CacheManager getCacheManager() {
        final int ttl = 12;
        final int maxCacheSize = 1012;

        GuavaCacheManager result = new GuavaCacheManager();
        result.setCacheBuilder(CacheBuilder
                .newBuilder()
                .expireAfterWrite(ttl, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                .maximumSize(maxCacheSize));

        return result;
    }
}
```

My Scala Class

```
@Component
class MerchantDataGateway {

  @Autowired
  var fmcsProxy: MerchantResource = null;

  @Cacheable
  def getAllMerchants(): List[MerchantViewModel] = {
    val merchants = getAllMerchantsFromFMCS()
    merchants.map(merchant => MerchantViewModel.getLightWeightInstance(merchant))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a name to the @Cacheable annotation:

```
@Cacheable(Array("MerchantDataGateway.getAllMerchants"))
```

Answer (score 0):

It needed a name, or an entry for the value

```
@Cacheable(value = Array("MerchantDataGateway.getAllMerchants")
```